# Office 365 SMTP sending mails failed for some account

Tags: c#, smtp

I tried 2 Office 365 accounts for SMTP mail sending. One is ok, the other one failed. I am pretty sure the account name and passwords are right.

Error message:

> Message = "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client
>   was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client
>   was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
>   [DM3PR11CA0008.namprd11.prod.outlook.com]"

C# code:

```
    int port = 587;
    int.TryParse(configuration["smtp:port"], out port);
    string host = configuration["smtp:server"] ?? "smtp.office365.com";

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(host, port);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    //client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(configuration["smtp:username"], configuration["smtp:password"]);

        await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
```

Comment: `smtp:username` - why does your email and password look like this ?

Comment: "smtp:username" is the configuration key name for username. I actually tried hard code username and password in the code, got same error.

Comment: I can send mail out using my personal email account (username) and password, but when I use another email account ( support@mycompany.com ) and password, I caught error.

Comment: if you use custom domain/email host/sever , make sure to change the client address and port accordingly :)